# POST example for Microsoft graph following their nodejs tutorial

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm a new fang in these things and I don't understand how a restful API works :(

At this moment I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph in order to read and send mails from a NodeJS web with Outlook 365 API. In MS developer web there is a good tutorial about how to use the GET method... Is there similar tutorials for POST and PUT methods?

I'm following another tutorials, but the few changes between develop environments and frameworks do hard to undestand it.

Thanks in advances!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a good tutorial that has POST and GET methods. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-apponlytoken-rest-sample. However, this tutorial reads and adds calendar events to the users calendar. But the post methods are all the same just different in API calls (instead of calendar you would do mail). I hope this helps.